# How do I extract specific values from a DataFrame and add them to a list?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dataframe

Sample DataFrame:

```
      id             date       price   
93   6021501535   2014-07-25    430000      
93   6021501535   2014-12-23    700000    
313  4139480200   2014-06-18    1384000   
313  4139480200   2014-12-09    1400000
```

first_list = []
second_list = []

I need to add the first price that corresponds to a specific ID to the first list and the second price for that same ID to the second list.

Example:
first_list = [430,000, 1,384,000]
second_list = [700,000, 1,400,000]

After which, I'm going to plot the values from both lists on a lineplot to compare the difference in price between the first and second list.

I've tried doing this with groupby and loc and I kept running into errors. I then tried iterating over each row using a simple for loop but ran into more problems...

I would appreciate some help.

Comment: What is the logic behind choosing this pair of values?

Comment: I'm new to programming so what I'm asking may sound silly. Like I mentioned above though - I'm going to plot the values from both lists when I'm done. The actual DataFrame is over 10000 rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your question I think it's not necessary to save them into a list because you could also store them somewhere else (e.g. another DataFrame) and plot them. The functions below should help with filling wherever you want to store your data.

```
def date(your_id):
    first_date = df.loc[(df['id']==your_id)].iloc[0,1]
    second_date = df.loc[(df['id']==your_id)].iloc[1,1]
    return first_date, second_date

def price(your_id):
    first_date, second_date = date(your_id)
    price_first_date = df.loc[(df['id']==6021501535) & (df['date']==first_date)].iloc[0,2]
    price_second_date = df.loc[(df['id']==6021501535) & (df['date']==second_date)].iloc[0,2]
    return price_first_date, price_second_date

price_first_date, price_second_date = price(6021501535)
```

If now for example you want to store your data in a new df you could do something like:

```
selected_ids = [6021501535, 4139480200]
new_df = pd.DataFrame(index=np.arange(1,len(selected_ids)+1), columns=['price_first_date', 'price_second_date'])

for i in range(len(selected_ids)):
     your_id = selected_ids[i]
     new_df.iloc[i, 0], new_df.iloc[i, 1] = price(your_id)
```

new_df then contains all 'first date prices' in the first column and all 'second date prices' in the second column. Plotting should work out.